# Android tabs show wrong fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

*Hello*, I'm trying to implement an Activity with tabs. Some tabs contain a fragment that shows simple list, others a tree view like list. 
The fragments with simple list work fine, while I'm having troubles with the one which shows tree view like list: the tree are build properly, but I get them in the wrong tabs. In the first tab I always see the content of the second one, and swiping back or expanding/collapsing the tree produces a new unwanted substitution of the whole tree.

I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong. I hope you can suggest me what to do. Thanks in advance!
Here's my code:

Pager Adapter:

```
 public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final List<ListFragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();


public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
{
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public ListFragment getItem(int index) {

    return mFragmentList.get(index);

}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

   return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
public void addFragment(int index, boolean tree) {
   Bundle b=new Bundle();
   String category= Items.getCategoryByIndex(index);
   b.putString(Items.CATEGORY,category);

   ListFragment fragment;
   if(!tree) {
       fragment = new ContentFragment();

   } else {
       fragment = new TreeFragment();

   }

   fragment.setArguments(b);
   mFragmentList.add(fragment);
   mFragmentTitleList.add(Items.getCategoryByIndex(index));
}
}
```

This is the TreeFragment class:

```
public class TreeFragment extends TreeViewFragment {

TreeListAdapter mAdapter;

public TreeFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle b = getArguments();
    String category = (String) b.get(Items.CATEGORY);

    GlobalVariables.dataList = Items.getTreeNodeByCategory(category);

    GlobalVariables.nodes = TreeViewLists.LoadInitialNodes(GlobalVariables.dataList);

    TreeViewLists.LoadDisplayList();

    mAdapter = new TreeListAdapter(inflater.getContext());
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}
}
```

and in the activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private ViewPager mViewPager;
 private PagerAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

   // (...) Content creation (...) 

    mAdapter.addFragment(0, true);
    mAdapter.addFragment(1, true);
    mAdapter.addFragment(2, true);
    mAdapter.addFragment(3, true);
    mAdapter.addFragment(4, false);
    mAdapter.addFragment(5, false);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

Comment: show your fragments in the order you want to show, in your `getItem()` method of your adapter put a switch statement and return fragment in the order of your wish.

Comment: Should I return the fragments of `mFragmentList` (not working) or instantiating them directly in the switch? Thanks

Comment: instantiate them, that should work.

Comment: I tried to do something like this in the `getItem(int index)` method:

`ListFragment f;
        Bundle b= new Bundle();
            switch(index) {
                case 0:
           b.putString(Items.CATEGORY,Items.getCategoryByIndex(index));
                    f = new TreeFragment();
                    f.setArguments(b);
                    return f; (...)`
but still not works

Comment: I also tried to display the value of the index with `Log.d("Index", String.valueOf(index));` , it assumes incorrect values when I switch to one tab to another and they change order everytime. Where could the error be? Maybe the viewpager?

Comment: I believe the order changes every time you add the items to the list. You can also try providing the index of the fragment while you're adding them to the array list like `list.add(_index_, _your fragment_);` and return the list like you're doing currently.

Comment: I tried to instantiate the fragments in the activity, put them in a map such as `Map<String,Fragment> fragmentMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Fragment>()`, I passed this map to the PageAdapter. 
Now the position in the `getItem(position)` method is correct, but all tabs show the same fragment (the latest one put in the map). Why this?